# PageviewController DataSource Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, objectdatasource, uipageviewcontroller

I have two Pageviewcontroller data source methods  like this

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

and want to add one more to it using **willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex** and have written it like given below but pointer is not hitting it noticed after adding breakpoint to it

I think coding for datasource method name is written wrong

```
- (void) pageViewController:(PageViewController *)pageViewController willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex
```

If someone can help me in correcting it so that pointer should hit this method when execute this project.

Will appreciate help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this the method?

```
– pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:
```

Comment: By the way this method is in the pageViewController delegate, not the data source.

Comment: Was this the method you were looking for?

Comment: Actually i mtrying to copy one method from Leaves project in Github - (void) leavesView:(LeavesView *)leavesView willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex, by using this method it is updating navigation bar page numbers without using [_navBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO]; when pages are turned over

Comment: I'm sorry that was not the method you were looking for. Can you send me the link for the project in Github?

Comment: You can download Leaves Delegate and use that method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in either [`UIPageViewControllerDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDataSource.html) nor [`UIPageViewControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDelegate.html).

The most similar method to what you intent to do, is probably `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` in the delegate.

Comment: Actually i mtrying to copy one method from Leaves project in Github - (void) leavesView:(LeavesView *)leavesView willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex, by using this method it is updating navigation bar page numbers without using [_navBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO]; when pages are turned over

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t think you can just copy code intended to be used with that project into another project that uses `UIPageViewController`. Maybe you should use Leaves, or try to use `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:`, which, except the name, and the argument, will provide you with mostly the same callback.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504150/backbarbuttonitem-shows-navbar-title-on-it-and-updates-each-time-when-page-is-tu  if you can check my this question then you will have idea of my problem i m having

Comment: i found this - (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
 maybe this will help me and solve my problem i will try this